# Algorithm in finding combination group of number

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I'm currently stuck on a part of an application I am working on. I don't want to copy all the code and paste it here but let me go directly straight to the point with a simple example:

Suppose I have a string "abcdefg", I am trying to find an algorithm that would get all the possible grouping without exchanging the characters, for example:

```
abcdeg
a, b, c, d, e, f, g
ab, c, d, e, f, g
..
..
abc, def, g
..
ab, cd, efg
..
and so on...
```

I think the example is pretty much the point. Can anyone provide me a pseudo-code? I understand Java, C, and C++ as well, so maybe a code snippet on those language is better, but if not pseudo-code is fine and I'll try to implement it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's surprisingly simple. Lop off the first letter and associate a 0 or a 1 with the remaining letters. A 1 means place a comma just before the letter. A 0 means don't.

E.g. 001100 corresponds to abc,d,efg.

The notation I'm using is a simple map of a number increasing from zero expressed in binary.

So three things, (i) count integers, (ii) convert to binary, (iii) use that binary as the comma positioning rule.

The stopping condition is obvious.

Comment: Interesting... yeah it does sound simple, but it coming up with this idea is not.. cause if it is, I would have thought of doing it...Anyways, thanks so much, all I need to do now is get the max digit, then generate the combinations of binary starting from 0 to the max digit, then use comma's where the binary digit '1' is found.

Comment: Your loop starts from 0 and ends at "two to the power of (one less the length of your string), minus one". So 0 to 63 in your example.